# Could Replacing current version of php-common Cause Any Issues?

Tags: php, linux, centos, mbstring

I am trying to install mbstring in CentOS final release 5.6 (final). However, I get this error:

`Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-45.el5_11 is needed by package php-mbstring-5.1.6-45.el5_11.x86_64 (updates)`

I understand that I have to install the version of php-common 5.1.6-45.el5_11 so I attempt to do so using this:

`rpm -ivh ftp://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/centos/5.11/updates/x86_64/RPMS/php-common-5.1.6-45.el5_11.x86_64.rpm`

But then I get a message saying that there is a newer version of php-common already installed:

`package php-common-5.3.10-1.w5.x86_64 (which is newer than php-common-5.1.6-45.el5_11.x86_64) is already installed
    file /etc/php.ini from install of php-common-5.1.6-45.el5_11.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.3.10-1.w5.x86_64`

My question is that if is it possible to replace the current version installed of php-common with the one mbstring needs in order to be installed without causing major issues to the configurations on the server?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: no. you can't just replace it. php modules are compiled against a specific core version of PHP's internal API. you can't just take a 5.3 binary module and load it into a version 5.1 php core. the APIs won't match and the module will refuse to load.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MarcB . it makes total sense to me. However, do you have an idea why the system wouldn't just use the current installed version of php-common when attempting to install mbstring?

Comment: you should be asking why it installed mbstring 5.1 in the first place, if you've got php 5.3 installed.

Comment: Do you think updating mbstring would fix the issue? @MarcB

Comment: like I said, you can't mix/match binaries. if you're running php 5.3, then you need libraries compiled against 5.3.

Comment: Thanks for your help @MarcB. I was trying to install it because a wordpress plugin requires the md_string extension enabled on the server in order to run and i was thinking maybe it is the mbstring because i personally have never heard about the md_string extension i even google it.